# Installed Scrapy on Python 3.4 (not compatible), installed Python 2.7 and can't install Scrapy for Python 2

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy

Using Windows 8. I installed pywin32, then Microsoft Visual C++ Studio 2010, then installed Scrapy.

I later found out that Scrapy is not compatible with Python 3. Stupid I know...

I read up and install Python 2.7 after that. I can't seem to install Scrapy using "pip install Scrapy" or "easy_install Scrapy". If I use those commands from the Python27 folder, it tells me it already exists in C:\Python34 folder.

I tried changing the registry key to change the default version of Python the command prompt uses but this does not work for some reason. I did check as below.

```
C:\>ftype|find /I "python"
Python.CompiledFile="C:\Python27\python.exe" "%1" %*
Python.File="C:\Python27\python.exe" "%1" %*
Python.NoConFile="C:\Python27\pythonw.exe" "%1" %*
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `pip` for python2. If you don't have it installed for python 2 install it with [get-pip.py](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py), download the file and run:

```
python get-pip.py
```

Each python installation has.needs it's own  pip.

Comment: I did that and used


    `pip install scrapy`


it gave me this
    C:\Python27>pip install scrapy
    Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): scrapy in c:\python34\lib\site-packages

Comment: how did you install python2.7?

Comment: when you type python which shell starts 2 or 3?

Comment: python 3, I changed my registry to use python2 but it did not work, i think i may have to remove python 3 from my PATH

Comment: There should be no problem using either, have you added C:\Python27;`C:\Python27\Scripts` to your path?

Comment: I have both c:\Python27 and c:\python34 in my path, I think this may be causing the problem.

Comment: do you have `c:\Python27\Scripts` also? When you type `python` what interpreter starts?